# How to add quantity to a rails form (create n records when submitting)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a library-like booking system. I want to make a form for adding books in stock, allowing the user to choose a book and choose a library (both are collection_select). Book has a many-to-many relationship with Library, through the stock_items table.

What I can't figure out is how can bring in the quantity, so that the user can add a number of instances of the same book to a chosen university. How should I approach implementing this quantity-type feature. It should create a chosen amount of records in the join table.

Here's my form (currently creates only 1 instance at a time):

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :choose_book %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:book_id, Book.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>

    <%= f.label :choose_library %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:library_id, Library.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>


    <%= f.submit "Add item in stock", class: "btn btn-info" %>
<% end %>
```

StockItem model

```
class StockItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :library
    belongs_to :book

    has_many :bookings, foreign_key: :stock_id, dependent: :destroy

    validates :availability, presence: true
    validates :library_id, presence: true 
end
```

Library model

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :stock_items
    has_many :books, through: :stock_items

end
```

Book model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :year_of_publication, presence: true, length: { maximum: 4 }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
    validates :name, presence: true

    has_many :stock_items,      dependent: :destroy
    has_many :libraries,        through: :stock_items
    has_many :contributions,    dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :authors,      through: :contributions
    has_many :bookings,         through: :stock_items

    has_many :book_images, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :libraries
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :stock_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contributions

    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

A bit of the StockItemsController

```
def create
    @item = StockItem.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
        flash[:success] = "Item added to stock"
        redirect_to stock_items_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Item has not been added to stock!"
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def new
    @item = StockItem.new
  end

  private

    def item_params
        params.require(:stock_item).permit(:library_id, :book_id, :availability)
    end
```

Comment: first of all you have to add quantity attribute to your stock_item table to store quantity..

Comment: @Gagan that depends on whether a StockItem represents "a collection of the same book in the library" or whether it represents a single physical book.  If it's the latter then quantity doesn't work.  I think he needs to expand his schema to have separate models for "a collection of the same book in the library", which **would** have quantity, AND a separate model for individual stock items (ie individual books that get checked out).

Comment: @MaxWilliams : thanks for your reply.. I can learn this thing also as I am new Bee..

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is systemic, rather than syntaxic, meaning you have to consider your system rather than the specific action syntax

--

**M-to-M**

You specifically need to look at the `many-to-many` association you've deployed here

Your population of the `StockItem` table is basically a way to create a collection for each `library`, and so you should look at the many `collection` based methods which ActiveRecord provides (specifically [`<<`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and [`.delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html))

Bottom line is that instead of creating new records for your `StockItem` model, I would just add to the collection of both `library` - giving you the files you need to make it work

--

**Collection**

As you're using `has_many :through`, you can add multiple instances of the same record to your collection (as opposed to `has_and_belongs_to_many`, which only permits single instances of records, as there is no `primary_key`)

This means you'll be able to just add books individually to the collection, and then use the `sum` method of SQL to calculate the quantity:

```
#app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb
class StockItemsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @library = Library.find params[:stock_item][:library_id]
       @book = Book.find params[:stock_item][:book_id]

       @library << @book
   end
end
```

--

**Quantity**

This is opposed to the idea that you can add a `qty` attribute to your `StockItem` model, and then use the [`increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21) method:

```
#app/controllers/stock_items_controller.rb
Class StockItemsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @item = StockItem.find_by(library_id: params[:stock_item][:library_id],book_id: params[:stock_item][:book_id])
      @item ? @item.increment!(:qty) : StockItem.create(stockitem_params)
   end
end
```